# Scala spark reduce by key and find common value

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a file of csv data stored in as a sequenceFile on HDFS, in the format of `name, zip, country, fav_food1, fav_food2, fav_food3, fav_colour`. There could be many entries with the same name and I needed to find out what their favourite food was (ie count all the food entries in all the records with that name and return the most popular one. I am new to Scala and Spark and have gone thorough multiple tutorials and scoured the forums but am stuck as to how to proceed. So far I have got the sequence files which had Text into String format and then filtered out the entries

Here is the sample data entries one to a line in the file

```
Bob,123,USA,Pizza,Soda,,Blue
Bob,456,UK,Chocolate,Cheese,Soda,Green
Bob,12,USA,Chocolate,Pizza,Soda,Yellow
Mary,68,USA,Chips,Pasta,Chocolate,Blue
```

So the output should be the tuple (Bob, Soda) since soda appears the most amount of times in Bob's entries.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io._

var lines  = sc.sequenceFile("path",classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text]).values.map(x => x.toString())
// converted to string since I could not get filter to run on Text and removing the longwritable

var filtered = lines.filter(_.split(",")(0) == "Bob");
// removed entries with all other users

var f_tuples = filtered.map(line => lines.split(",");
// split all the values

var f_simple = filtered.map(line => (line(0), (line(3), line(4), line(5))
// removed unnecessary fields
```

This Issue I have now is that I think I have this `[<name,[f,f,f]>]` structure and don't really know how to proceed to flatten it out and get the most popular food. I need to combine all the entries so I have a entry with a  and then get the most common element in the value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I tried this to get it to flatten out, but it seems the more I try, the more convoluted the data structure becomes.

```
var f_trial = fpairs.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
// the resulting structure was of type org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Interable[(String, String, String)]
```

here is what a println of a record looks like after f_trial

```
("Bob", List((Pizza, Soda,), (Chocolate, Cheese, Soda), (Chocolate, Pizza, Soda)))
```

Parenthesis Breakdown

```
("Bob", 

List(

(Pizza, Soda, <missing value>),

(Chocolate, Cheese, Soda),

(Chocolate, Pizza, Soda)

) // ends List paren

) // ends first paren
```

Comment: Do you need one, single most popular food for everyone or do you need to get a favourite food per name?. Could you provide a sample od you f_simple data and what do you want to get?

Comment: @Niemand right now I just need the name and the most popular food for that name (in the future I might need to get the top 3 most favourite or what not but I just need a base to start on), I was thinking the same thing, I should provide the data set and have just done so, thanks for replying.

Comment: The first entry for Bob only has two favourite foods. Do the records all have the same number of columns or not?

Comment: @Paul, thanks for replying, Each entry can have at most 3 favourite foods, I can be less but definitely not more. And the trailing comma will be included even if there is only 1 or 2 entries(just edited that in).

Comment: Not got time for a proper answer, but I think you need to flatten to `(name, food)` (or maybe `((name, food), 1)`) then `reducebyKey` to `((name,food),total)`, `Map` to `(name, (food, total))`, `reduceByKey` again (just keeping the biggest total in the reduce step). That gives you `(name, (food, total))` of the most popular food for each person

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found time. Setup:

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-scratch").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val data = """   
  Bob,123,USA,Pizza,Soda,,Blue
  Bob,456,UK,Chocolate,Cheese,Soda,Green
  Bob,12,USA,Chocolate,Pizza,Soda,Yellow
  Mary,68,USA,Chips,Pasta,Chocolate,Blue
  """.trim

    val records = sc.parallelize(data.split('\n'))
```

Extract the food choices, and for each make a tuple of `((name, food), 1)`

```
    val r2 = records.flatMap { r =>
      val Array(name, id, country, food1, food2, food3, color) = r.split(',');
      List(((name, food1), 1), ((name, food2), 1), ((name, food3), 1))
    }
```

Total up each name/food combination:

```
    val r3 = r2.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
```

Remap so that the name (only) is the key

```
    val r4 = r3.map { case ((name, food), total) => (name, (food, total)) }
```

Pick the food with the largest count at each step

```
    val res = r4.reduceByKey((x, y) => if (y._2 > x._2) y else x)
```

And we're done

```
    println(res.collect().mkString)
    //(Mary,(Chips,1))(Bob,(Soda,3))
```

EDIT: To collect all the food items that have the same top count for a person, we just change the last two lines:

Start with a List of items with total:

```
val r5 = r3.map { case ((name, food), total) => (name, (List(food), total)) }
```

In the equal case, concatenate the list of food items with that score

```
val res2 = r5.reduceByKey((x, y) => if (y._2 > x._2) y 
                                    else if (y._2 < x._2) x
                                    else (y._1:::x._1, y._2))

//(Mary,(List(Chocolate, Pasta, Chips),1))
//(Bob,(List(Soda),3))
```

If you want the top-3, say, then use `aggregateByKey` to assemble a list of the favorite foods per person instead of the second `reduceByKey`

Comment: This is brilliant. I was approaching the problem the wrong way, I guess from more traditional perspective. Can you just explain how you would handle ties when it comes to foods with the same count. Right now only ones is displayed.

Comment: What result do you want when you have foods with the same count? The simplest would be to build a list of foods that have the same (max.) count.

Comment: that would be perfect, I have another parsing program that can take a list and do manipulate it later down the line, where would the logic for that go? I was also having issues using aggregateByKey. I really appreciate all the help you guys

Comment: OK, done that. Not sure I understand your second point, but maybe try yourself and post another question if you get stuck?

Comment: And don't forget to upvote the answers that helped! :-P

Comment: Thanks that would be perfect, let me read a bit more into this and see if I can do it on my own, Thanks again!

Comment: @ArchetypalPaul can you please translate it to DF(spark sql) if i open a new question?

Comment: I don't have time, but ask the question anyway as someone else may answer

Answer (score 4):

Solutions provided by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32177240/1560062) and [mattinbits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32177978/1560062) shuffle your data twice - once to perform reduce-by-name-and-food and once to reduce-by-name. It is possible to solve this problem with only one shuffle.

```
/**Generate key-food_count pairs from a splitted line**/
def bitsToKeyMapPair(xs: Array[String]): (String, Map[String, Long]) = {
  val key = xs(0)
  val map = xs
    .drop(3) // Drop name..country
    .take(3) // Take food
    .filter(_.trim.size !=0) // Ignore empty
    .map((_, 1L)) // Generate k-v pairs
    .toMap // Convert to Map
    .withDefaultValue(0L) // Set default

  (key, map)
}

/**Combine two count maps**/
def combine(m1: Map[String, Long], m2: Map[String, Long]): Map[String, Long] = {
  (m1.keys ++ m2.keys).map(k => (k, m1(k) + m2(k))).toMap.withDefaultValue(0L)
}

val n: Int = ??? // Number of favorite per user

val records = lines.map(line => bitsToKeyMapPair(line.split(",")))
records.reduceByKey(combine).mapValues(_.toSeq.sortBy(-_._2).take(n))
```

If you're not a purist you can replace `scala.collection.immutable.Map` with `scala.collection.mutable.Map` to further improve performance.

Comment: More efficient, yes.   But not as clear, I'd argue. And just like @mattinbits,_`.toSeq.sortBy(-_._2).take(1) is `maxBy(_._2). Another plus for mine is that it works better if there are many, many, options for choice of food (not that likely, I admit!)

Comment: `sortByKey` allows you to take arbitrary number of elements and collection API doesn't provide `topBy` method. Regarding large number of options I cannot agree. Lets say user has N "favorite" foods, each occurs only once in the dataset. You have to transfer  this data twice and the only benefit is reduced memory footprint when you compute final answer.

Comment: The problem is if the list of foods for one user won't fit in one node (not very likely, as I said). Also, it's `maxBy`, not `toBy` and it is provided: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@maxBy[B](f:A=>B):A. You don't need an "arbitary number of elements", you need 1 (hence your `take(1)``.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make my intention clear :) Regarding _wont fit on one node_ it is extremely unlikely. Assuming 16GB per worker and (64 bytes per pair * number-of-pairs) + object header for map you can store 1e8 pairs leaving enough space for combine if I count correctly :)

Comment: Yep, pretty unlikely. Still prefer mine for clarity, but with real-world datasets, the efficiency of yours is good. It's a pity the Scala collection API doesn't have `top` (and the Spark one does't have `topByKey` - it does have` top`  for a plain RDD)

Comment: Thats a shame, although it shouldn't be that hard to implement using [`PriorityQueue`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue).

Comment: @zero323 This solution is really good, and I really like it, though I prefer the former for the sense of readability. But it gave me a great entry way into considering the efficiency analysis of the scala code I would write.

Comment: @zero323 can you please comment out and explain more about the code, it would be very helpful

Comment: @zero323 please, also advise any learning source to learn to understand spark and scala at such advanced level. every source shares just simple word count example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}


object Main extends App {

  val data = List(
    "Bob,123,USA,Pizza,Soda,,Blue",
    "Bob,456,UK,Chocolate,Cheese,Soda,Green",
    "Bob,12,USA,Chocolate,Pizza,Soda,Yellow",
    "Mary,68,USA,Chips,Pasta,Chocolate,Blue")

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("example")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

  val lineRDD = sc.parallelize(data)

  val pairedRDD = lineRDD.map { line =>
    val fields = line.split(",")
    (fields(0), List(fields(3), fields(4), fields(5)).filter(_ != ""))
  }.filter(_._1 == "Bob")

  /*pairedRDD.collect().foreach(println)
    (Bob,List(Pizza, Soda))
    (Bob,List(Chocolate, Cheese, Soda))
    (Bob,List(Chocolate, Pizza, Soda))
   */

  val flatPairsRDD = pairedRDD.flatMap {
    case (name, foodList) => foodList.map(food => ((name, food), 1))
  }

  /*flatPairsRDD.collect().foreach(println)
    ((Bob,Pizza),1)
    ((Bob,Soda),1)
    ((Bob,Chocolate),1)
    ((Bob,Cheese),1)
    ((Bob,Soda),1)
    ((Bob,Chocolate),1)
    ((Bob,Pizza),1)
    ((Bob,Soda),1)
   */

  val nameFoodSumRDD = flatPairsRDD.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)

  /*nameFoodSumRDD.collect().foreach(println)
    ((Bob,Cheese),1)
    ((Bob,Soda),3)
    ((Bob,Pizza),2)
    ((Bob,Chocolate),2)
   */

  val resultsRDD = nameFoodSumRDD.map{
    case ((name, food), count) => (name, (food,count))
  }.groupByKey.map{
    case (name, foodCountList) => (name, foodCountList.toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse.head)
  }

  resultsRDD.collect().foreach(println)
  /*
      (Bob,(Soda,3))
   */

  sc.stop()
}
```

Comment: This is sort of similar, rather than being a "complete example" of my approach. Note I avoided `groupByKey` deliberately. From the Spark doc: "Note: This operation may be very expensive. If you are grouping in order to perform an aggregation (such as a sum or average) over each key, using `PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey` or `PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey` will provide much better performance."

Comment: And this `foodCountList.toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse.head` is a convoluted way to say `maxBy (_._2)`

Comment: I was referencing your comment inc. "Not got time for a proper answer" not your answer, your answer must have gone up while I was writing mine, apologies.

Comment: No problem. Good to give the OP some alternatives

Comment: @mattinbits This is really similar to Paul's though I ended up using the logic from here to filter out the empty food entries as well as use the index based accessing as I had a lot more fields in my final project. Thanks.

Comment: @mattinbits can you please translate it to DF(spark sql) if i open a new question?